# How to remove a node from XmlDocument loaded XML

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8, windows-phone, xmldocument

I have repeated xml fragment like this below in a larger document. How to remove all occurrences of `well`, `total` and `fee` using XmlDocument?

```
<res>
  <pay>
    <well/>
    <total/>
    <fee/>
    <tit>
        <qr>asdf</qr>
        <id>
            <num/>
        </id>
    </tit>
  </pay>
</res>
```

Comment: XDocument is the new XmlDocument

Answer (score 0):

Load the xml into an XDocument (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use linq to find and remove the nodes in question.

Then its just a duplicate of [XDocument deleting a node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481622/xdocument-deleting-a-node)

If you really want to use the XMLDocument instead of XDocument class then this is a dup of [Removing nodes from an XmlDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611/removing-nodes-from-an-xmldocument)